# How are the Koopa Trace Walking and Picture Match challenges graded?

Tags: super-mario-odyssey

In the Trace-Walking challenges, Mario must

> walk along a path, which he can no longer see after a few moments; if he gets a high enough score, he wins a Power Moon. For the Moon Rock bonus moon, he must simply earn a higher score on the same challenge.

In the Picture Match challenges, Mario must

> take the parts of a Goomba’s or his own face and place them on a blank face. If he scores high enough, he gets a Power Moon. Thanks to Moon Rocks, he can earn a second moon in these challenges by doing this again with nothing but the face’s outline helping him.

My question is: **how are these graded?** Toad in the Picture Match puzzles claims that it’s graded on accuracy, but that doesn’t explain how much is deducted for what type of errors.

I’m grouping these two challenges together because I’m assuming that, while each is slightly different, the scoring will be along the same lines for each, since both involve matching something to a disappearing background. But correct me if I’m wrong.

Comment: Is it not indeed just now accurately you can re-trace the path or reassemble the picture? Surely that covers all the 'errors' Mario could make. Are you looking for some kind of formula?

Comment: @Kozaky Basically, yes. Obviously the further Mario strays from the path the less points he’ll score; my question is precisely how much he loses for what distance away over how much of the path.

Comment: You seem to have combined two questions into a single post. I recommend editing your question to focus on a single mini game.

Comment: @StevenVascellaro I understand, and, as I indicated in my final paragraph, I grouped them together because I am assuming that they are scored similarly.

Answer (score 2):

I would guess that:

- Trace-Walking is graded on the perimeter of the outline the straightness/circularity of the edges, and the position of the corners (if any).
- Picture Match is graded on the accuracy of each piece's position and rotation.

The grading would be primarily based on deviation. A perfect score would be an exact recreation. A 100 is still awarded for very minor deviations from the target. As the amount of deviation from the target increases, the score goes down, probably linearly.

(disclaimer: this is mostly instinct and logic, with not much hard proof)

Comment: And I can tell you already that this is wrong, since it’s possible to get a score of 100 without making a perfect recreation of it.

Comment: That would be the "A 100 is still awarded for very minor deviations from the target." (perhaps the "very" is underselling it) I don't know how large the grace window is because that would take way too many retries to figure out, but it's there.

Comment: @DonielF: There's still a reasonable error margin that the game allows for. "exact recreation" is not the same as "pixel perfect".